# How to insert values into array and map in sql databricks?

Tags: sql, arrays, insert, databricks

I'm able to create a schema in databricks but how can I insert data into the array and map?
I just cannot find any information regarding SQL. It's all about python, scala, but I'm looking for sql only.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb.arraytest (
  capacity array<INT>,
  mapper MAP<INT, STRING>,
  device_type STRING,
  location_id INT
)
```

Gives me the expected schema:

```
+-------------+-----------------+ 
| col_name    | data_type       | 
+-------------+-----------------+
| capacity    | array<int>      | 
| mapper      | map<int,string> | 
| device_type | string          |
| location_id | int             |

# Partitioning
Not partitioned
```

But I just don't know how can I insert values into the array and the map?

None of what I tried worked:

```
INSERT INTO
  mydb.arraytest
VALUES
  (array<1,2,3>, (1, 'mapstring1'), 'string1', 1)
  (<1,2,3>, ....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Array](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array) and [Map](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#map) functions start with brackets, so something like this should work for you:

```
%sql
INSERT INTO arraytest
VALUES (Array(1,2,3), Map(1, 'mapstring1'), 'string1', 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, much appreciated!